# Find duplicate codes in a list

Tags: algorithm

There are N (N <= 50) codewords representing different letters, (e.g. "000110", "0", etc). And they will form a list:
(e.g "0110","00","111","001100","110"). I want to find the shortest ambiguous code from this list. In this case, the answer would be "001100110". Which can either be formed by "001100" + "110" or "00" + "110" + "0110".

Naive exhaustion obviously doesn't work here. I couldn't find a solution that make sense. Any thought on this? Any hints or solution will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

A similar problem can be found here: https://www.spoj.com/problems/AMCODES/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've constructed two sequences that match up to their length, but the aren't the same length, for example:

```
001100
00110 <-- this is 00 and 110
```

Then, if you want to extend the shorter sequence, the unmatched part of the longer sequence -- in this case "0" -- determines what you can do next, since any code you add must match it.  If you don't end up with a matching sequence, then you will have another unmatched part that will determine which codes you can use next.

Since you always want to extend the shorter sequence, every "unmatched part" will be a code word or a suffix of a code word.  There are O(N) of these, where N is the length of the input.

Imagine the directed graph with a node for every code word and suffix, starting with "" and with an edge from each suffix to the any suffix you could transition to by adding a code word that matches it.

For example you would have an edge from "0" to "110", because the code word "0110" starts with "0", leaving "110" unmatched.

Let the cost of each edge be the length of the code word, and your problem is just to find the shortest path from "" back to "" in this graph that doesn't start with matching code words.

You can use Dijkstra's algorithm to find this shortest path.

If you build a trie to help you find matching code words quickly, then the whole algorithm takes O(N^2) time (again, in the length of the input), which is hardly any time at all when there are no more than 50 code words, unless of course they are very long.

Comment: Also may I ask a few questions regarding the construction of the directed graph? What does the nodes and edges represent? It is not very clear in your answer. Also, why does a path going from "" to "" implies that there are two sets of codewords forming the same code?

Comment: From my understanding, there exists an edge from A to B if and only if there is a codeword which is in the form of (a suffix from A + a prefix from B). Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean suffix.  From the example, if "0" is the unmatched part of the longest sequence, and you match it by adding "0110"  to the shorter sequence, then the "0" matches and "110" -- a suffix -- is left over and is now unmatched.

Comment: There is an edge A->B if there is a code word W such that A = WB, OR if there is a code word W such that W = AB

Comment: Oh yes It should be suffix, I got that part now

Comment: I see now, so an edge is simply a transition from one "unmatched" suffix to another "unmatched" suffix. Marked as accepted now!